# PHP: Watermark won't work

Tags: php, watermark

I've created a watermark function as below :

**index.php**

```
<?php
include 'core.inc.php';

do_watermark('bg1.jpg', 'logo1.png');
?>
```

**core.inc.php**

```
<?php
header ( 'Content-type: image/jpeg' );

function do_watermark($source_image, $logo) {

$watermark = imagecreatefrompng ( $logo );
$watermark_width = imagesx ( $logo );
$watermark_height = imagesy ( $logo );

$image = imagecreatetruecolor ( $watermark_width, $watermark_height );
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg ( $source_image );

$image_size = getimagesize ( $source_image );

$x = $image_size [0] - $watermark_width - 10;
$y = $image_size [1] - $watermark_height - 10;

imagecopymerge ( $image, $watermark, $x, $y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 40 );
imagejpeg ( $image );
}
?>
```

But when calling `do_watermark('bg1.jpg', 'logo1.png')`, show nothing.

`bg1.jpg` and `logo1.png` is along `index.php`.

Any help would be great.

Comment: You should move the call to `header()` from core.inc.php to index.php.  It doesn't fix your problem but it is better code design as you are defining functions in one file and producing output in the other, as opposed to it being mixed.

Comment: Have you bothered checking for errors? e.g. seeing if any of the gd functions returned a boolean false, indicating failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the watermark image usually going to be smaller than the image being watermarked? You have created your working image to be the watermark's size rather than the source image's size -- is that what you really want? I'm not sure about the x and y coordinates -- the larger the watermark is, the further right and (up or down?) it will be, as x and y increase with the size of the watermark. I would think about positioning it (x and y) as a function of both the image size and the watermark size.

You also have it hard coded for JPEG image and PNG watermark. You could get the image types from the file names or from the getimagesize() call ('mime' entry). Consider making it more flexible this way.

Answer (score 1):

There were some major problems in the code you had written, this should work, but compare it to yours to see what was wrong.

```
<?php

function do_watermark($source_image, $logo) {

    $watermark      = imagecreatefrompng($logo);
    $watermark_width    = imagesx($watermark);
    $watermark_height   = imagesy($watermark);

    $image          = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image);
    $image_width        = imagesx($image);
    $image_height       = imagesy($image);

    $x = $image_width - $watermark_width - 10;
    $y = $image_height - $watermark_height - 10;

    imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $x, $y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 40 );

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($image);

    imagedestroy($image);

}

?>
```